# Proving $f(x)=x$ is continuous at $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: analysis

I am trying to solve this problem. The problem is that I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to choose $\delta$ and $\epsilon$.

> Prove that $f(x)=x$ is continuous at $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

To show, I know $\forall \epsilon \gt 0 \space \exists \delta \gt0$ such that $|x-x_0| \lt \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)| \lt \epsilon$

*My work:*

$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|x-x_0|$

so if we choose $\delta \lt 1$ then, we choose $\delta:=\min \{1, \epsilon\} \gt0$.

then $|x-x_0| \lt \delta \lt 1$  would imply $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|x-x_0| \lt \epsilon$.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: $\delta=\epsilon$ will do fine. No need to do any $\min[1,\epsilon]$ stuff on a linear function. That's for when a function does things far away that you don't want to have to deal with.

Comment: what do you mean by that's for when a function does things far away?

Comment: When proving that $g(x)=x^2$ is continuous at $x_0$, that's a function that becomes steeper and steeper. To avoid having to deal with that unlimited steepness far away from $x_0$, we choose $\delta$ to be the smallest of $1$ and some other value. That makes things a lot easier as we only have to deal with the steepness in the interval $[x_0-1,x_0+1]$. Your $f$ doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

In continuity proofs, you get to choose what $\delta$ is going to be. Therefore, just choose $\delta=\epsilon$. Then you have that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ since $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|x-x_0|$.

Comment: so you are saying to make my choice of $\delta$ equal to $\epsilon$? what about my choice of $\epsilon$, is that choice independent?

Comment: You don't get to choose $\epsilon$. You only get to choose $\delta$.